# What is the most efficient way to convert hh:mm:ss or mm:ss or ss to millis?

Tags: javascript, performance

Here's my function to convert hhmmss or mmss or ss to millis. 
How can I improve it?

```
hhmmssToMillis(hhmmss) {
   let time= hhmmss.split(':').reverse();
   let millis = 0;
   switch(time.length) {
     case 1: 
         millis = parseInt(time[0]) * 1000;
         break;
     case 2: 
         millis = (parseInt(time[1]) * 60 + parseInt(time[0])) * 1000;
         break;
     case 3: 
         millis = (parseInt(time[2]) * 60 * 60 + parseInt(time[1]) * 60 + parseInt(time[0])) * 1000;
         break;
   } 
   return millis; 
}
```

Comment: If the code works, you should post it on CodeReview.

Comment: Why do you think there's a performance problem in the code?

Comment: a) drop the `reverse` b) use the distributive law to avoid multiplications c) (advanced, not neccessarily faster) use fall-through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definetly improve it by shortening it to:

```
const [seconds = 0, mins = 0, hours = 0] = hhmmss.split(':').reverse();
return ((+hours * 60 + +mins) * 60 + +seconds) * 1000;
```

And while this is probably not the "fastest" way, its at least fast enough for all usecases.